# The proof of the Keisler-Shelah theorem

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory

I don't understand the proof of the Keisler-Shelah theorem on elementary equivalence and ultrapowers.  I am referring to the version appearing Chang and Keisler (Third Edition, p. 394), but Shelah's original proof contains the essentially same problem.

The notion of $\kappa$-consistency is introduced to keep track of the induction hypothesis.  For sets $F, G$ of functions on a cardinal $\lambda$ into another $\mu$ (subject to certain conditions), a filter $D$ on $\lambda$, a triple $(F, G, D)$ is $\kappa$-consistent if (I) $D$ is generated by a subfamily of cardinality at most $\kappa$, and (II) for a sequence $\{f_\rho\}_{\rho<\beta} \subseteq F$ (where $\beta$ is a cardinal less than $\mu$) and $\{\sigma_\rho\}_{\rho<\beta} \subseteq \mu$, $f \in F$, and $g\in G$, the set $\{\xi < \lambda \mid (\forall \rho < \beta)[f_\rho(\xi) = \sigma_\rho], f(\xi) = g(\xi)\}$ generates a proper filter together with $D$.

Just by the form, the clause (II) appears to be vacuously true if $G=0$ , in which case $\kappa$-consistency is just the clause (I), which is a condition solely on $D$.  In fact, the base case of the induction is the claim that there is a $\kappa$-consistent $(F, \emptyset, \{\lambda\})$, and to build the isomorphism one only needs $\kappa$-consistency of $(F, \emptyset, D)$.

But this cannot be the case, as serious effort is given to constructing $F$ such that $(F, \emptyset, D)$ is $\kappa$-consistent.  What have I misunderstood?  Or is there a typo?

Comment: I am not knowledgeable about these sorts of things at all, but I completely agree with you that condition II appears vacuous if $G$ is empty. when the authors construct the $F$ you mention in your last paragraph, what is their proof like that $(F,\varnothing,D)$ satisfies condition II?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom In the case $D = \{\lambda\}$, they show that the set ${\xi < \lambda \mid (\forall \rho < \beta)[f_\rho(\xi) = \sigma_\rho]\}$ is nonempty.  Note that this set is different from the set appearing in the definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I attended a course taught by Tom Scanlon in Spring 2015, in which we actually went through all the gory details of Keisler-Shelah in class (this is even more astonishing when you consider that the topic of the class was model theory of valued fields!). I just checked my notes, and they contain the definition of $\kappa$-consistent just as written in Chang and Keisler, but I've circled "for all $f\in F$ and $g\in G$" and "$f(\xi) = g(\xi)$" and wrote "drop this condition if $G = \varnothing$". I would have checked everything quite carefully at the time, so I suspect this fix works.

Maybe a clearer approach would be to define two notions:

1. "$(F,D)$ is weakly $\kappa$-consistent" means $D$ has a generating set of size $\leq \kappa$ and for all $\beta<\mu$, all families $(f_\rho)_{\rho<\beta}$ of distinct functions, and all families $(\sigma_\rho)_{\rho<\beta}$, the set $\{\xi<\lambda\mid \forall \rho<\beta\, f_\rho(\xi) = \sigma_\rho\}$ generates a proper filter together with $D$.
2. "$(F,G,D)$ is $\kappa$-consistent" means $D$ has a generating set of size $\leq \kappa$ and for all $\beta<\mu$, all families $(f_\rho)_{\rho<\beta}$ of distinct functions, all families $(\sigma_\rho)_{\rho<\beta}$, and all $f\in F$ and $g\in G$, the set $\{\xi<\lambda\mid f(\xi) = g(\xi)\text{ and }\forall \rho<\beta\, f_\rho(\xi) = \sigma_\rho\}$ generates a proper filter together with $D$.

Then whenever Chang and Keisler write "$(F,0,D)$ is $\kappa$-consistent" - which they do many times over the next few pages! - you can read it as "$(F,D)$ is weakly $\kappa$-consistent".

Comment: Why did you all read this proof??? Anyway, I will check myself if this fixes the definition.

Comment: It's a great question! I think the reason is that when axiomatizing certain classes of valued fields, you end up working with fields $K$ and $K'$ such that the residue fields $k$ and $k'$ are elementarily equivalent and the value groups $\Gamma$ and $\Gamma'$ are elementarily equivalent. To make some arguments easier, you'd like to pass to elementarily equivalent fields $L$ and $L'$ whose residue fields and value groups are actually isomorphic. You can do this if you assume some set theory to get saturated models, but you can also do it in ZFC using Keisler-Shelah.

Comment: ... and for some reason Tom thought it was worthwhile to write out every last detail of Keisler-Shelah on the board instead of just citing the result. Maybe he got bored of all the algebra and wanted to spend some time doing set theory as a relaxing break in the middle of the semester (haha).

Comment: @AlexKruckman I think actually doing out the details of KS **is** a good idea in this setting, at least when focusing on the value groups specifically: set theory builds character. *(Ba-dum chsssh, sorry.)*